# Minecraft: right click shows cursor

Tags: java, cursor, minecraft

I play Java progammed game Minecraft.

When I place an block by using right click, it shows the cursor position over the Java application as long I hold it down. It is annoying because on Windows there wasn't such problem.

How to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Switching to Gnome solved the problem.

Also, Gnome is more Windows-like than Ubuntu's default desktop environment.